# Processing java application

Tags: java, processing

Simple question, is there a way to compile processing in java as an application rather than an applet?

As it is now, if I run it as an application  it just terminates on launch

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _'to compile processing in java as an application rather than an applet?'_? Do you want to run it as a service as opposed to a standalone application?

Comment: @August define 'compile processing', please.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to run your applet?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm very new to the java environment.
All I need it to be able to send params to my executable applet.

It has to run serverside eventually

Comment: Sounds like a you're not sure what you actually want to do. Do you want to know why your application stops after it's done? If you want your application to run and wait for input, you should implement some kind of a loop. But I'm not sure if that's what you're wanting to know..

Comment: I'm very certain what I want, just not by what means I will be able to achieve it. 
I need to run processing on a server: send the script an image, process it and send it back, simple

Comment: With "processing", do you mean the stuff you can find on [Processing.org](http://processing.org/)? You need to explain that because "processing" is a common word, people don't understand what you mean if you don't explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Java-Process stops directly after starting it has been started, then it is probably a missing non-daemon thread.

Create a Thread, that waits for input and has a `while(shouldRun){doSomethingOrWait()};`

You should also add an `ShutDownHook` to get that endless-loop terminated.

**update:**
applets don't run at serverside. Please try to explain more precise, what you plan to do.

*update 2:*
For such a vague question, I only can give a vague answer:

Solution 1: 
Install a tomcat webserver and create a Servlet. Send the data to the servlet and start your job at serverside, after the URL has been loaded.

Solution 2: Create a RMI server and send the jobs via RMI.

Comment: Sorry for being vague about what I need to do. I need to run processing on a server: send the script an image, process it and send it back

Comment: Thank you so much, now I just need to learn how to do solution 1, Cheers!